# Laravel Nova - How to hide 'Create' button from HasMany field?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-nova, eloquent-relationship

I've User model which has HasMany relation with Post model. When I include a field for HasMany in User resource of Nova, I see there is [`Create post` button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrAJl.png). How do I remove/hide that button?

Answer (score 3):

this question is answered in [laravel nova official documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#hiding-entire-resources)

in my case i have **user** model and **order** model, **user** Hasmany **order** i added

```php
public function addOrder()
{
    return false;
}
```

on user policy now **create role** button is gone on user detail page 
[this is a screenshot of user detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpGg5.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with [`Policies`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#policies).

According to the documentation:

> If a policy exists but is missing a method for a particular action, the user will not be allowed to perform that action. So, if you have defined a policy, don't forget to define all of its relevant authorization methods.

So in your case, if you want to hide the button completely, just create a policy for your resource (`PostPolicy`) and don't implement the `create` method.

Comment: The problem with this is that I want users to be able to make entries, just not from an item that has a HasMany rule for those entries...

Answer (score 2):

You need to 2 things here.

1. In your Post resource

   public static function authorizable()
       {
           return true;
       }
2. Now create policy for Post and `return true` for all methods except create, for create `return false` and in `AuthServiceProvider.php`

put

```
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me, the last thing you want to do is set a policy blocking creation of the sub-resource referenced by the HasMany rule by setting a policy. The reason is that setting this `addX()` policy to `false` on the "Has" side of the `HasMany` not only blocks the creation of the sub-resource from the resource detail view, it also produces permission errors when creating the sub-resource from its page view, specifically that creation of the resource with references to the "parent" or "Has" is forbidden by the policy. Which when you think about how broad the permission statement of `addClassName()` is, isn't actually surprising.

Thus my solution ended up having to be butt ugly CSS. Just why is this the only way to do page dependant hiding of the create button. This should be a `HasMany::make("")->canCreate(false)` declaration in the `Nova/*.php` view file.

Anyway here's the CSS, hopefully, it helps someone.

```css
div[dusk="parent-class-detail-component"] div[dusk="has-many-child-class-index-component"] a[dusk='create-button'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for the solution, you can authorise attaching/detaching resources in your policies:

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#authorizing-attaching-detaching

So in this case, you have a `UserPolicy` to which you add a function:

```
attachPost(User $user, User $model, Post $post)
{
    return false;
}
```

The `$user` variable is the user that is signed in, the `$model` variable is the user page that is viewed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by incorporating an `authorizedToCreate(Request $request)` method in the Nova model. Inside this method, I checked if `$request['viaResource']` is equal to the `relatedModel`. Depending on the result, I returned either `true` or `false`.